# UWP change style of ListView DataTemplate in a MasterView

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, master-detail, listviewitem

This is the structure of the XAML:

```
    <controls:MasterDetailsView
        ItemsSource="{x:Bind Artists}">
        <controls:MasterDetailsView.MasterHeader>
            // Some Code
        </controls:MasterDetailsView.MasterHeader>
        <controls:MasterDetailsView.ItemTemplate>
            // Some Code
        </controls:MasterDetailsView.ItemTemplate>
        <controls:MasterDetailsView.DetailsTemplate>
            <DataTemplate x:DataType="data:ArtistView">
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <RelativePanel HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
                        // Some Code
                    </RelativePanel>
                    <ListView
                        x:Name="AlbumsListView"
                        Grid.Row="1"
                        HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                        ItemsSource="{x:Bind Albums}"
                        SelectionMode="None">
                        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate x:DataType="data:AlbumView">
                                <Grid Margin="10,0,0,30">
                                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                                        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <RelativePanel>
                                        // Some Code
                                    </RelativePanel>
                                    <ListView
                                        x:Name="SongsListView"
                                        Grid.Row="1"
                                        HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                                        ContainerContentChanging="SongsListView_ContainerContentChanging"
                                        IsItemClickEnabled="True"
                                        ItemClick="SongsListView_ItemClick"
                                        ItemsSource="{x:Bind Songs}"
                                        SelectionMode="Single">
                                        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                                            <DataTemplate x:DataType="local:Music">
                                                // Some Code
                                            </DataTemplate>
                                        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                                    </ListView>
                                </Grid>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    </ListView>
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </controls:MasterDetailsView.DetailsTemplate>
    </controls:MasterDetailsView>
```

I am trying to highlight an item of `SongsListView` (it's inside another listview) whose music is playing by changing the foreground. I implemented it in the ContainerContentChanging but the foreground will only be changed after reload the page. I want it to be updated in real time. How can I do that?

I registered a MusicSwitching event which will take place when the current playing music is changed, so that I can set the foreground of the item that has been played to black, and the foreground of the item to be played to a highlight color.

```
    public async void MusicSwitching(Music current, Music next)
    {
        await Dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.High, () =>
        {
            var item = ArtistMasterDetailsView.Items.First((a) => (a as ArtistView).Name == next.Artist);
            var container = ArtistMasterDetailsView.ContainerFromItem(item);
        });
    }
```

I can first find the item correctly, but the container is null. Why? I thought it is the DataTemplate that contains the item.

Comment: The method **ArtistMasterDetailsView.ContainerFromItem** you wrote is not very good, even if you get it, it is just the container of the item from outer materview.So the best way is use **Binding**.You can bind the Foreground of controls to a property(e.g. bool IsPlaying) in Music class.And in your MusicSwitching method to set the current.IsPlaying false and next.IsPlaying true.

Comment: Binding doesn't change color on the fly. I need to reload the page to make it work. @Faywang-MSFT

Comment: If you want to receive property change notifications from the bound object, the class in which this property is located needs to inherit from **INotifyPropertyChanged**, so that when your property value changes, the control bound to it will be notified with the change.In addition,you should change the Mode to the **OneWay**.The default binding mode is OneTime which will bind once.If you do the same, still can't change, can you show more code about your binding?

Comment: @Faywang-MSFT Could you please check this [link](https://github.com/SeakyLuo/SMPlayer/blob/master/SMPlayer/ArtistsPage.xaml)? I used ObservableCollection for the bound collections and have set all their modes to OneWay.

Comment: @Faywang-MSFT Just to be clear, the style I want to change is `SongsListView`'s item. Its item source is defined in the **ArtistsPage.xaml.cs** and the datatype is defined in the **Models** folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to highlight an item of SongsListView,the simple way is to set a property(I saw you have set a IsPlaying method,I changed it to a property) in Music class to bind to the control in item you want to hightlight.About Binding,you can refer to this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/data-binding/data-binding-in-depth).

First, you should let the **Music** class inherits from **INotifyPropertyChanged** to listen property change notifications.

```
public class Music : IComparable<Music>, INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        ......
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged = delegate { };
        public bool IsPlaying {

            set { 
                IsMusicPlaying = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
            get {
                return IsMusicPlaying;
            }
        }

        public void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
        {
            // Raise the PropertyChanged event, passing the name of the property whose value has changed.
            this.PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
```

Then,bind the property to the control in item you want to highlight.

```
<Page.Resources>
        <local:ColorConvert x:Name="MyConvert"></local:ColorConvert>
</Page.Resources>
<FontIcon
         x:Name="PlayingIcon"
         Margin="0,0,16,0"
         FontFamily="Segoe MDL2 Assets"
         Foreground="{StaticResource SystemColorHighlightColor}"
         Glyph="&#xE767;"
         RelativePanel.AlignLeftWithPanel="True"
         Visibility="{Binding Name, Converter={StaticResource MusicVisibilityConverter}}" />
<TextBlock
         x:Name="MusicNameTextBlcok"
         Grid.Column="1"
         Width="720"
         Text="{x:Bind Name}" 
         Foreground="{x:Bind IsPlaying,Converter={StaticResource MyConvert},Mode=OneWay}"/>
```

.cs

```
public class ColorConvert : IValueConverter
    {
        // this does not include sublevel menus right now
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
        {
            if (value.ToString() == "False")
            {
                return Helper.BlackBrush;
            }
            else
            {
                return Helper.GetHighlightBrush();
            }

        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException(); 
        }
    }
```

Finally,when the MusicSwitching is triggered,you can reset IsPlaying property.In this case,the foreground will also change together.

Comment: I didn't make `IsPlaying` a property because I saved the playlist (a list of music) to my local computer. I was thinking that this might be a waste of memory since I can check it at run time. Do you think this might be an issue?

Comment: It's okay, it's not going to make a bad impact.

Comment: Thank you! I have asked a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57478990/uwp-visualstatemanager-pointerover-does-not-work) that has not received a good answer. Could you please take a look at that?