# UWP AcrylicBrush HostBackdrop cause Color Changes when Window loses focus

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, acrylic-material

I have `Grid` whose `Background` will be altered according to the color of album art at the run time. And I change the `Background` using the following code:

```
        return new AcrylicBrush()
        {
            BackgroundSource = AcrylicBackgroundSource.HostBackdrop,
            TintOpacity = 0.75,
            TintColor = Color.FromArgb(bgra[3], bgra[2], bgra[1], bgra[0])
        };
```

However, the `HostBackdrop` is causing the trouble for me. As you can see from the images I post below, the background turns white it loses focus. It is normal when the window has focus. And when I change the `HostBackdrop` to `Backdrop`, the color no longer changes. But I do want to use `HostBackdrop`.

How can I achieve that? Thanks in advance!

[image: Unfocused]

[image: Focused]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently `AcrylicBrush` only works when the window gets focus, you can view the document with a description of [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/style/acrylic#usability-and-adaptability)

If you need to set the color of the `AcrylicBrush` when the window loses focus, you can use the `FallbackColor` property.

Best regards.

Comment: Thank you! Problem solved! Could you please look at my other unanswered questions?

Comment: Thank you for your mark, my companion is researching your question, reply will be soon.

Comment: I really appreciate your helpfulness. Could you take a look at this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57478990/uwp-visualstatemanager-pointerover-does-not-work)?